# returning a two dimensional array by multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, dill, pathos

In the following code which is an example of my main code, I have tried to use `pathos.multiprocessing` to increase the speed of iteration of a loop. The output of each iteration which has implemented with multiprocessing is a **2-D array**. I used `pathos.multiprocessing` instead of `multiprocessing` since I wanted to use it in my **class method**. I have used `apipe` method of the `pathos.multiprocessing` to collect the output in a list but it returns an empty list. I have no idea why it fails

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pathos.multiprocessing as mp
class Testsystematics(object):
      def __init__(self, x, y, NTH = None, THMIN = None, THMAX = None, NRESAMPLE = None):
         self.x        = x
         self.y        = y
         self.nbins    = NTH
         self.bmin     = THMIN
         self.bmax     = THMAX
         self.nresample= NRESAMPLE
         self.bins     = np.linspace(self.bmin, self.bmax, self.nbins+1, True).astype(np.float)
         self.sample   = np.array([[random.choice(range(len(self.y))) for _ in xrange(len(self.y))] for i in range(self.nresample)])
         self.result_list=[]
      def log_result(self, result):
          self.result_list.append(result)
      def bootstrapping(self, k):
          xi_p     = np.zeros(self.nbins, float)
          xi_m     = np.zeros(self.nbins, float)
          nind     = np.zeros(self.nbins, float)
          for i in range(len(self.x)):
              for j in range(len(self.x)):
                  if (i!=j): 
                     sep= np.sqrt(self.x[i]**2+self.x[j]**2)
                     index= np.searchsorted(self.bins, sep , side='right')-1 
                     sind = np.sin(sep)
                     if ((sep< self.bins[-1]) and (sep>=self.bins[0])):
                        xi_p[index] += sind*(np.mean(y)-np.median(y))
                        xi_m[index] += sind*np.std(y)
                        nind[index] += 1.0
          for i in range(self.nbins):
              xi_p[i]=xi_p[i]/nind[i]
              xi_m[i]=xi_m[i]/nind[i]
          return np.vstack((xi_p,xi_m))
      def twopcf(self):   
         if (self.sys_type==1):
            pool = mp.ProcessingPool(16)
            for n in range(self.nresample):
                pool.apipe(self.bootstrapping, args=(n,), callback=self.log_result)

shape,scale=0.5, 0.6
x=np.random.gamma(shape, scale, 10000)
mu1, sigma1 = 0, 0.5 # mean and standard deviation
mu2, sigma2 = 0.1, 0.7 # mean and standard deviation

y = np.random.normal(mu1, sigma1, 1000)+np.random.normal(mu2, sigma2, 1000)
sysTest=Testsystematics(x, y, NTH = 10, THMIN = 0, THMAX = 5, NRESAMPLE = 100)
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the `pathos` author.  I tried your code, and it runs, but produces no error and produces no result in `result_list`.  I believe that is because you are using `apipe` incorrectly.  The correct use of `apipe` is as follows:

```
>>> import pathos
>>> def squared(x):
...   return x**2
... 
>>> pool = pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessingPool()
>>> res = pool.apipe(squared, 5)
>>> res.get()
25
```

`self.bootstrapping` takes `self` and `k`, so you have to provide a `k` in the pipe call when you calling it as an instance method.  There is no `callback` -- if you want a callback, you'd need to add one to your function.

Note that the return value is retrieved by (1) getting a return object, and (2) by calling `get` on the return object.

From you use of `apipe` within a `for` loop, that points me to suggest you use `pool.amap` (or `pool.imap`) instead -- then you can do the for loop in parallel.

Comment: Do you think returning a 2-D array each time in a loop would be a problem for multiprocessing?

Comment: Not unless it's huge.  It also depends on how it's pickled… so multiprocessing will do it inefficiently by default, while numpy knows innately how to make a smaller pickle.  Remember, multiprocessing is copying these objects… so you have speed and memory considerations.

Comment: Well, your comment about using `get` function was helpful. However when I use still `apipe` and look whether it uses all the core, the code is distributed between cores but except one that use the full power cpu the rest don't use any cpu power. Basically it still works on one core.

Comment: Absolutely.  `apipe` is once core only… it's "a pipe".  What you want is `amap`, which is asynchronous parallel batch.